# Default Wordpress Query for a Specific Custom Post Type URL

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, theme-development

I need a little more clarification on the default query for a specific custom post type url. I am learning how to use WP default functions and queries via Udemy. However, I feel like this little part I need either better clarification or confirmation from the community. In the video in Udemy, it uses the variable `$query` as an argument in a function in order to customize the default query for a custom post type. However, I do not see anywhere else in the training that shows where that variable comes from. Yet, somehow, we are still able to implement it as an object in order to look into it for other data points or to customize the default query for a custom post type.

```
    function university_adjust_queries($query) {

    if(!is_admin() && is_post_type_archive('program') && $query->is_main_query()){
        $query->set('orderby', 'title');
        $query->set('order','ASC');
        $query->set('post_per_page', -1);
    }

    if(!is_admin() AND is_post_type_archive('event') AND $query->is_main_query()){
        $today = date('Ymd');   
        $query->set('meta_key', 'event_date');
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
        $query->set('order','ASC');
        $query->set('meta_query', array(
            array(
              'key' => 'event_date',
              'compare' => '>=',
              'value' => $today,
              'type' => 'numeric'
            )
          ));
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','university_adjust_queries');
```

Is this variable a default variable in the WordPress application that everyone is used to using or is it just something that was created on the fly?

If it is a default variable widely used by WP, then is this the key variable I can go to no matter what the custom post type or default post type is? Is it always stored in the same `$query` variable?

Is that the reason why the instructor decided to use it, although I can't see it anywhere else? Is it just common knowledge now?

Thank you

Comment: can you include the code that you're asking about? Not everybody is familiar with the Udemy courses, or what the instructor did, nor will many people watch the courses to find out what you're referring to, or spend the money to gain access to them. Use the `Edit` link under the list of tags to edit your question and include the missing context

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for the input and yes, I will go ahead and add the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you shared is for an action/filter named `pre_get_posts`. WordPress will run this action before it uses the arguments for `WP_Query` objects to generate SQL. It is an opportunity for you to modify that queries arguments/parameters. By doing this it will call all the functions attached to that action/filter/event.

> Is this variable a default variable in the WordPress application that everyone is used to using or is it just something that was created on the fly?

**No.** You can see where the variable came from, it's a function parameter:  `...ries($query) {`. This isn't a WordPress thing, this is a basic programming thing.

Take this example:

```php
function foo( $bar ) {
    echo $bar;
}
$banana = 'hello';
foo( $banana );
```

Where does `$bar` come from? It is not a global, it's just the name of the first argument for the function named `$foo`. You do not need to know how WordPress calls the function, just that it gets called.

> If it is a default variable widely used by WP, then is this the key variable I can go to no matter what the custom post type or default post type is? Is it always stored in the same $query variable?

No, it isn't. The reason it's called `$query` is because that's the name of the first function argument. If you renamed it to `$oranges` it would be called `$oranges`, there is nothing special about the choice of name. It's probably called `$query` because it's a query.

This code is just as valid:

```php
function university_adjust_queries( WP_Query $university_query ) {

    if(!is_admin() && is_post_type_archive('program') && $university_query->is_main_query()){
```

So is this:

```php
function university_adjust_queries( WP_Query $kittens ) {

    if(!is_admin() && is_post_type_archive('program') && $kittens->is_main_query()){
```

But you wouldn't use kittens as a name because it's not very readable and gets confusing.

> Is that the reason why the instructor decided to use it, although I can't see it anywhere else? Is it just common knowledge now?

You wouldn't use the functions argument variables outside the function, that makes no sense. Take this example:

```php
function foo( $bar ) {
    echo $bar;
}
foo( "banana" );
echo $bar; // <- this doesn't work, we are not inside the foo function so $bar doesn't exist here, it isn't the same variable
```

This is now touching on the programming concept of "scope". Think of it like unconnected conversations, the `$bar` inside the function and the `$bar` outside the function are not the same variable, they just happen to have the same name, and have no other connection. There is also nothing special about the choice of name, `$veranda` or `$purple` are equally valid choices.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was very well explained. It connected many dots for me.